# php loop through dates not exceeding month ending date

Tags: php, date, datetime

Below is my script which works fine for all starting dates except 29,30 and 31. Can any one make it work for all dates starting from 1....31st it should increment by month and donot exceed last date ?

```
  $startdate='2010-01-30';
  $enddate='2011-01-30';
    while ($startdate <= $enddate)
     { 
      echo date('Y-m-d', $startdate ) . "\n";
      $startdate = strtotime('+1 month', $startdate);
    }
```

Comment: It's obvious because Feburary doesn't have 31st date.

Comment: @Yogesh Of course it's obvious. Give him the fix instaed of downvoting.

Comment: @JanDoggen: It's hard to fix when what he wants is not provided. We could guess that he wants the last day of each month, but it's not certain that that's what he would want.

Comment: @JanDoggen I haven't downvoted him :) Maybe someone else has done that.

Comment: Sorry guys I was assuming to much. @Asad What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @JanDoggen And the fix may be that OP has to use `$startdate='2010-01-28';
  $enddate='2011-01-28';`.

Comment: check my answer below for solution. It just increments timestamp by one day every time to take the timestamp into next month and then use 'Y-m-t' in date function to extract the last day of that month

Comment: @all i want to increment date e.g($startdate="2010-01-29" and $enddate="2010-12-29" ) increment it by month it sholud give 2010-02-29, 2010-02-28 , 2010-03-29 ....... so on till 2010-12-29 . kindly help me with this any one

Comment: @AsadKayani you want same day of month for each of the months that fall between start date and end date. Its just that if the month of the day is not valid for a particular month, you want last day of that month. Am I right?

Comment: @rakeshjain yes exactly same thing i want

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<?php
  $startdate='2010-01-31';
  $enddate='2011-01-31';
    $timestamp=  strtotime($startdate);
    while ($startdate <= $enddate)
     { 
      $startdate = date('Y-m-t', $timestamp);
      echo $startdate . "<br/>";
      $timestamp = strtotime('+1 days', strtotime($startdate));
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
    $startdate = strtotime('2010-01-29');
    $enddate = strtotime('2011-01-31');
$inc = 1;
    while($startdate <= $enddate )
    {
        $date = date("t", $startdate);
        $numbersofdays = date('d',$startdate);
        $incDate = ($date - $numbersofdays) + 1;
        if ($startdate == $enddate || $inc==1) {
            echo date('Y-m-d',$startdate).  PHP_EOL;
        } else {
        echo date('Y-m-t',$startdate).  PHP_EOL;
       }

         $startdate = strtotime("+".$incDate." days", $startdate );
        $inc++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: this code just gives wrong out put this is problem statement i need solution of it dear

Comment: @AsadKayani: 31 is required for start date or you can take any date?

Comment: @ratneshdwivedi sir it must run with 29,30 and 31 too its must rest dates (1-28) are fine no issue with that . kindly make it run for 29,30 please

Comment: @AsadKayani: try this one

Comment: @ratneshdwivedi above code donot run for dates 28,29,30 how to take it?

Comment: @AsadKayani: check this one

Comment: @AsadKayani: have you tried this one?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like complicated code, but I believe this is what you required.

```
<?php
$startDate='2010-01-29';
$endDate='2013-12-30';
$startDateSplit = explode("-",$startDate);
$endDateSplit = explode("-",$endDate);
$starTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $startDateSplit[1], $startDateSplit[2], $startDateSplit[0]);
$numDaysStart = $startDateSplit[2];
$passThroughDelta = false;
$endTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $endDateSplit[1], $endDateSplit[2], $endDateSplit[0]);
while ($starTime <= $endTime)
{
      $startDate = date('Y-m-d', $starTime);
      echo $startDate . "\n";
      $startDateSplit = explode("-",$startDate);
      $numDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $startDateSplit[1],$startDateSplit[0]);
      echo $numDays . "\n";
      if($startDateSplit[1] == 12) {
         $startDateSplit[1] = 0;
         $startDateSplit[0]++;
      }
      if($numDaysStart > cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,     $startDateSplit[1]+1,$startDateSplit[0])) {
       $delta = $numDaysStart - cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,     $startDateSplit[1]+1,$startDateSplit[0]);
           $numDays = $numDays - $delta;
           $passThroughDelta = true;
      }
      else if ($passThroughDelta) {
           $numDays = $numDays + $delta;
           $passThroughDelta = false;
      }
      $starTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $startDateSplit[1], $startDateSplit[2]+$numDays,     $startDateSplit[0]);
}
```

Comment: your code gives wrong output if $startDate='2010-01-30';
$endDate='2013-12-30'; kindly help me with the script which runs correct with date 28,29,30 and 31.

Comment: Hi Asad, In this code I am trying to add the number of days in the month next to the startDate, see this line, $numDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,         $startDateSplit[1]+1,$startDateSplit[0]); ... I have tried with the date provided by you in this script. I got the output as 2010-01-30
28
2010-02-27
31
2010-03-30 so on. can you tell me where is the error? So that I can try more.

Comment: i want to give any date between 1,2,3,.....31st of month and it should run for next dates also like if i pass $startdate="2010-02-28" it should output 2010-01-28 2010-02-28 2010-03-28 uptil last date , and for case like $startdate="2010-01-29" expected output 2010-01-29 2010-02-28 2010-03-29 so on...

Comment: I have edited my code to adjust as per your requirement, Please see it work for you. I have tested the code with the following date, $startdate="2010-02-28" , $startdate="2010-02-29" .. And it works fine for me.